# Distribution of Current in Kirchoff's Junction Law

Tags: current, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I know that Kirchoff's law says that the incoming current is equal to outgoing current.

But I want to understand his: suppose we have 4 wires like the one in diagram.

[image]

So let us consider current i1, comes to the junction and gets split into three direction towards i2, i3, i4 and similar is the case with current i2 but then why we imagine only the current i3 and i4 as outgoing current whereas current is also going to i1 and i2.

May be I am missing something but I am stuck on this problem for very long.

Comment: Your statement of KCL is a bit vague. Better is: the sum of the currents towards a junction is equal to the sum of currents away from that junction. So in your case I1+I2=I3+I4

Comment: Yeah that's the definition given in the book. But consider it as follows the current i1 at reaching the node has three path to go and similarly for i2 not only two path as shown.

Comment: It's just an example, same here: http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/4446431200_1487510279.png Current entering the node must be equal the current that is leaving the node. That's all. What is important is that the current cannot magically disappear. What's enter the node must leave the node.

Comment: Once drawn on paper, you cannot imagine other ways again. The currents i1 and i2 are entering the nodes and those currents have to leave the nodes. Only path available is other two paths. So, they take those paths. One is named i3 and the other i4. i2 now cannot take path of i1 because, it is the net current which is being represented.

Comment: Yes . I saw that. But I Just want to understand that when i1 reaches the node it has three paths to go but why is outgoing current only in two paths

Comment: @Umar but i2 can take three path after reaching the node. Isn't it?

Comment: Okay. Another try from me. Assume a pipe connection instead of wires. You connect two taps at ends i1 and i2. Two taps both force water out but at different force. Where so you think, the water comes out? Only through the other two nodes,i3 and i4, because its the preferred path as it is of least resistance.

Comment: @Umar velocity is a vector and current is definitely not. But I am trying hard to understand your argument. Thanks.

Comment: @Umar Also imagine if you took two separate pipes with holes and join them together vertically what direction will the water flow in?

Comment: Two pipes, stacked one above the other do not have any node..so continues to flow in same direction. They indeed us same as single pipe . Isn't it?

Comment: @Umar they are not stacked above each other there are joined vertically. I am sorry to bother you but I honestly can't understand it.

Comment: @Umar so I understood it as: since there is already a current in i2 branch so it doesn't flow in a considerable amount. Also if resistance in both outgoing branch is equal then current in both branches are (i1 + i2)/2. Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just an example. You may imagine a different case or example if you want.

Any of those current may be inflowing or outflowing, as long as total current inflowing equals total current outflowing.

Also, currents inflow or outflow depending of the conditions in other nodes. If there is a negative voltage difference with respect to another node and an impedance low enough (i.e., finite) to it, then there will be an inflow of current.

Comment: So what are you saying is that i1 may the incoming current minus the outgoing one.

Comment: That way to look at it would be more close to kirchoff loop rule.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is that you consider i1 , after it reaches the node it has three paths to go isn't it ?

Comment: Well, in a narrow sense, yes. If i1 is coming from, say, a power supply and you connect it to three loads, then is has to split in three. What comes in must go out. The node itself doesn't sink any current.

Comment: So i1 is the net current of what we originally gave and what flown in from i2 ? And similarly with i2?

Comment: The author assumes that the I1 and I2 currents entering the node.

Comment: @Shivam Again: yes but only in a very narrow sense. For example, you might think about the following situation: i1 is the current supplied by a PSU to two loads, each drawing i3 and i4. Then you add a second PSU that supplies i2. The loads will be drawing the same i3 and i4, but now the first PSU is supplying less current i1'=i1-i2. Does that mean that there is current going into the first PSU, and that net current is i1-i2? NO, what's actually happening is that it needs to deliver less current thanks to the second PSU. i1' and i2 "combine" in the node and "split" afterwards as i3 and i4.

Comment: Oh!!! Now i got it. Thank you so much for you patience.Thanks once again.

Comment: A current entering a node *may* flow out through any of the wires connected to that node. But beware: an analysis is required to see if it can *effectively* do that. The way the currents inflow/outflow to/from one node depends heavily on the nodes at the other side of the wire and also on what's connected in-between.

Comment: @Enric  I understood it as: since there is already a current in i2 branch so it doesn't flow in a considerable amount. Also if resistance in both outgoing branch is equal then current in both branches are (i1 + i2)/2. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, you're getting the idea behind it. Let me reword your first sentence: since the "i2 branch" is supplying current to the node, the current from the "i1 branch" doesn't need to supply as much current as if it was "alone".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot suppose two current directions at the same time. If you consider i1 and i2 enter, and i3 and i4 are outgoing currents then you cannot consider current is outgoing i1 and i2 aswell...

The best thing you can do to proof it is to draw a simple circuit and write down the KCL equations. You can assume whatever currents direction you want, but once you have resolved the equations you will see which are the real "directions".

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit.

Comment: I am not supposing two directions. After i1 has reached the node it has three ways to go. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is circuit with 2 inputs and 2 outputs

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkg9MX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is circuit with 1 input and 3 outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNmBDK.png)</sup>

Here is circuit with 4 inputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffnZwP.png)</sup>